# Applying a (possibly unary) function recursively onto itself

Tags: haskell, grammar, l-systems

I am trying to express an L-system in Haskell https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system, specifically Lindenmayer's original L-system for modelling the growth of algae.

> variables : A B
>   constants : none
>   axiom  : A
>   rules  : (A → AB), (B → A)

For me the natural way to approach this problem is to apply the rules to each element in the list, which (to me) means that I could model the solution using some type of string substitution.

## Example:

For the list of "characters" [A, B, A we'd apply the rules and get [A → AB, B → A, A → AB] = [A, B, A, A, B] (for this model to play along nicely with Haskell you will have to regard AB as a list [A, B] which we will combine with any other results produced with the rules above).

I have produced the code included below which is complete with data constructors to not have to handle other characters than A or B,

```
data Letter = A | B deriving (Show, Eq)

type Alphabet = [Letter]

algae :: Alphabet -> Alphabet

algae = concat . map (\c -> if
                | c == A -> A:[B]
                | c == B -> [A])
```

The above code is such that calling it with itself as an argument yields the expected result, viz. that

```
algae $ algae $algae [A] =  [A, B, A, A, B]
```

Repeated applications work as expected.

What I want to accomplish next is for the function to apply recursively onto itself, but have failed to express this. By this I mean that I would like to be able to call the function, either as `algae [A]` or just `algae` (which would require a type signature change to `algae :: Alphabet`) which yields an infinite list that one would receive by applying algae onto itself infinitely many times.

Since I have admitted defeat I have looked at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lindenmayer-0.1.0.0/docs/Lindenmayer-D0L.html but I cannot comprehend the code as it is (yet) and also found other equally confusing implementations.

I've tried my best to attempt to use using `folds` and the `fix` function but have failed in doing so. I have also tried to borrow from other recursive definitions such as

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

But that approach fails since `zipWith` expects a binary operator.
Can this problem be solved without monads? If so, how?

Comment: It is worth noting that the `Monad` instance for `[a]` is actually just `concatMap`, and is not scary at all!

Comment: I wrote a thing on L-Systems in Haskell: http://reinh.com/notes/posts/2015-06-27-theoretical-pearl-l-systems-as-final-coalgebras.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `iterate`. I would also suggest a slight modification to your `algae` function to use pattern matching:

```
data Letter = A | B deriving (Show, Eq)

type Alphabet = [Letter]

algae :: Alphabet -> Alphabet
algae = concatMap f
  where f A = [A, B]
        f B = [A]

infAlgae :: [Alphabet]
infAlgae = iterate algae [A]

main :: IO ()
main = print $ infAlgae !! 3
```

Comment: That is almost what I am trying to accomplish, I would like for
`take 4 infAlgae` to be `[A,B,A,A,B]` instead of `[[A],[A,B],[A,B,A],[A,B,A,A,B]]` but I suppose I could figure out a way to wrap it somehow.
Nevermind, I see you have already done so using `!!`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I thought you might also be interested in how to efficiently produce an actual infinite list, `fibs` style:

```
import Data.List (stripPrefix)

data Letter = A | B deriving (Show, Eq)

type Alphabet = [Letter]

algae :: Alphabet -> Alphabet
algae = concatMap f
  where f A = [A, B]
        f B = [A]

infFromPrefix :: Eq a => ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
infFromPrefix rule prefix = inf where
    inf = prefix ++ case stripPrefix prefix (rule inf) of
        Just suffix -> suffix
        Nothing     -> error "Substitution does not preserve prefix"

infAlgae :: Alphabet
infAlgae = infFromPrefix algae [A]

main :: IO ()
main = print . take 100 $ infAlgae
```

And in GHCi:

```
*Main> :main
[A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A]
```

Comment: I realize now that I did not read the question very carefully. I was also not aware that the substitution preserves the prefix. Nice answer.